# Reverse Bit Order of 32-bit Integers

Tags: code-golf, bitwise

Write the shortest code to reverse the bit order of a 32-bit integer.

**Rules:**

1. Input is assumed to be a valid integer or string equivalent if your language doesn't support numerical values (e.g. Windows Batch).
2. Output must be a valid integer or string equivalent if your language doesn't support numerical values (e.g. Windows Batch).
3. Standard library only.
4. It may be a function or a complete program.
5. Input may be either from `stdin` or as a function argument.
6. Output must be either `stdout` or as a returned value.
7. If your language has a built-in or standard library function that does this in one step (e.g. `rbit` in ARM assembly), that cannot be used.

**Examples:**

Key:

1. decimal

   - binary
   - (reverse)
   - reversed binary
   - decimal output

Examples:

1. `-90` (8-bit example for demonstration)

   - `10100110b`
   - (reverse)
   - `01100101b`
   - `101`
2. `486`

   - `00000000000000000000000111100110b`
   - (reverse)
   - `01100111100000000000000000000000b`
   - `1736441856`
3. `-984802906`

   - `11000101010011010001100110100110b`
   - (reverse)
   - `01100101100110001011001010100011b`
   - `1704506019`

Note: Omissions are free game. If I didn't say it, and it's not one of the [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/14668), then it's completely allowed.

Comment: What is meant by "omissions" in "omissions are free game"?

Comment: Anything not explicitly stated in the rules.

Comment: Would a 16gb static table be counted as part of the program length?

Comment: @HotLicks According to the typical interpretation of program, yes.

Comment: language that only supports 8-bit inputs, can we take input as four 8-bit numbers?

Comment: @Sparr Yes. <placeholder text>

Comment: Windows Batch hater detected. :D

Comment: @Kroltan Actually, that's where I really learned when goto is or isn't a good thing. There are times when a structured goto is better than anything else, and I get annoyed on occasion on its lack of existence in JavaScript. If you could jump out of a for loop early and skip a section of code (like Python's for else), it could all but eliminate the need for exception handling (which can be a code smell of its own).

Comment: @Kroltan On the contrary, it is possible to abuse it. My first programs featuring goto tended to be slightly spaghetti code, especially when I hadn't learned yet about multi-statement if, else, and for statements.

Comment: Can I have the checkmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 assembly, 9 bytes

```
    xor eax, eax
    inc eax
myloop:
    shr ecx, 1
    adc eax, eax
    jnc short myloop
```

In byte form: `33 C0 40 D1 E9 13 C0 73 FA`, 9 bytes.

Comment: That again is exactly as long as my solution if you (a) obey the cdecl calling convention and (b) actually return from the function.

Comment: @FUZxxl Somehow, I didn't see your version.  You are completely correct.  I was thinking `__fastcall` and didn't have the `ret`.

Comment: This does need a `ret` to be a function (not a snippet), but there's no reason to use an inefficient calling convention like stack args.  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) (So @FUZxxl that part is a missed optimization in your version.  You could take an arg in EDX and return in EAX, and tell GCC for Linux about it with `__attribute__((regparm(2)) unsigned rbit(int dummy, unsigned x)`.  I think `__attribute__((ms_abi))` is not fastcall, so IDK how to tell GCC for non-Windows about this version.  Not that it matters, it's asm not C.)

Answer (score 26):

### MMIX assembly (28 Bytes)

#### 64 bit numbers

```
rbit:
    SETH $1,#0102 # load matrix in 16-byte steps
    ORMH $1,#0408
    ORML $1,#1020
    ORL  $1,#4080
    MOR  $0,$1,$0 # multiplication 1
    MOR  $0,$0,$1 # multiplication 2
    POP  1,0      # return
```

This assembles to:

```
rbit:
    E0010102 # SETH $1,#0102
    E9010408 # ORMH $1,#0408
    EA011020 # ORML $1,#1020
    EB014080 # ORL  $1,#4080
    DC000100 # MOR  $0,$1,$0
    DC000001 # MOR  $0,$0,$1
    F8010000 # POP  1,0
```

#### How does it work?

The `MOR` instruction performs a matrix multiplication on two 64-bit quantities used as two 8x8 matrices of booleans. A boolean number with digits *abcdefghklmnopqr<sub>2</sub>* is used as a matrix like this:

```
/ abcd \
| efgh |
| klmn |
\ opqr /
```

The `MOR` instruction multiplies the matrices represented by their arguments where multiplication is `and` and addition is `or`. It is:

```
/ 0001 \      / abcd \      / opqr \
| 0010 |  \/  | efgh |  --  | klmn |
| 0100 |  /\  | klmn |  --  | efgh |
\ 1000 /      \ opqr /      \ abcd /
```

and furthermore:

```
/ opqr \      / 0001 \      / rqpo \
| klmn |  \/  | 0010 |  --  | nmlk |
| efgh |  /\  | 0100 |  --  | hgfe |
\ abcd /      \ 1000 /      \ dcba /
```

which is the reverse order of bits of the original number.

#### 32 bit numbers

If you just want the reverse of a 32 bit number instead of a 64 bit number, you can use this modified method:

```
rbit:
    SETL   $1,#0408 # load first matrix in two steps
    ORML   $1,#0102
    MOR    $1,$1,$0 # apply first matrix
    SLU    $2,$1,32 # compile second matrix
    16ADDU $1,$2,$1
    MOR    $1,$0,$1 # apply second matrix
    POP    1,0      # return
```

assembled:

```
rbit:
    E3010408 # SETL   $1,#0408
    EA010102 # ORML   $1,#0102
    DC010001 # MOR    $1,$1,$0
    3B020120 # SLU    $2,$1,32
    2E010201 # 16ADDU $1,$2,$1
    DC010001 # MOR    $1,$0,$1
    F8010000 # POP    1,0
```

The first matrix multiplication basically works like this:

```
/ 0000 \      / 0000 \      / 0000 \
| 0000 |  \/  | 0000 |  --  | 0000 |
| 0001 |  /\  | abcd |  --  | efgh |
\ 0010 /      \ efgh /      \ abcd /
```

the corresponding octabyte is `#0000000001020408` which we load in the first two instructions. The second multiplication looks like this:

```
/ 0000 \      / 0001 \      / 0000 \
| 0000 |  \/  | 0010 |  --  | 0000 |
| efgh |  /\  | 0100 |  --  | hgfe |
\ abcd /      \ 1000 /      \ dcba /
```

The corresponding octabyte is `#0102040810204080` which we create from the first matrix like this:

```
SLU $2,$1,#32   # $2 = #0102040800000000
16ADDU $1,$2,$1 # $2 = $2 + $1 << 4
                     = $2 + #0000000010204080
                #    = #0102040810204080
```

The second multiplication is business as usual, the resulting code has the same length (28 bytes).

Comment: it's the first time I hear about matrix multiplication instruction on a CPU

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Not a matrix multiplication, but VAX had an [instruction to evaluate a polynomial](http://uranium.vaxpower.org/~isildur/vax/poly.html).

Comment: @nneonneo The `POLY` instruction of the VAX is basically a fused multiply-and-add with a builtin loop. Similar things also exist in modern architectures (like x86), but they usually don't have a builtin loop to evaluate an entire polynomial at once.

Answer (score 17):

### 80386 assembly (<s>13</s> 12 bytes)

As a function in AT&T syntax using the cdecl calling convention.

```
    # reverse bits of a 32 bit word
    .text
    .globl rbit
    .type rbit,@function
rbit:
    push $32       # prepare loop counter
    pop %ecx
0:  shrl 4(%esp)   # shift lsb of argument into carry flag
    adc  %eax,%eax # shift carry flag into lsb
    loop 0b        # decrement %ecx and jump until ecx = 0
    ret            # return
```

This function assembles to the following byte sequence:

```
6a 20 59 d1 6c 24 04 11 c0 e2 f8 c3
```

Broken down into instructions:

```
6a 20       push $32
59          pop %ecx
d1 6c 24 04 shrl 0x4(%esp)
11 c0       adc  %eax,%eax
e2 f8       loop .-6
c3          ret
```

It works like this: In each of the 32 iterations of the loop, the argument, which is located at `4(%esp)`, is right shifted by one position. The last bit is implicitly shifted into the carry flag. The `adc` instruction adds two values and adds the value of the carry flag to the result. If you add a value to itself, i.e. `%eax`, you effectively left-shift it by one position. This makes `adc %eax,%eax` a convenient way to left shift `%eax` by one position while shifting the content of the carry flag into the low-order bit.

I repeat this process 32 times so that the entire content of `4(%esp)` is dumped into `%eax`. I never explicitly initialize `%eax` as its previous contents are shifted out during the loop.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your last sentence, It's obvious now but I missed that.

Comment: I'm always happy to see assembly solutions on here :)

Comment: As discussed on other answers, use a convenient calling convention as recommended in [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) , or a custom convention.  One like x86-64 System V would work well, with the first arg in a register other than EAX or ECX.  That would save 2 bytes in `shr %edx`

Comment: Is there any way to pre-process inputs for `crc32 r32, r32` that makes it output the bit-reflection of one input?  I guess probably not, since the final output is the bit-reflection of the remainder polynomial division of a 96-bit temporary by 0x11EDC6F41, so it's probably hard to arrange for the *remainder* to be something derived easily from an input you want to reflect.

Answer (score 7):

### C,   <s>63</s>     <s>52</s>    48

**Original version:**

```
int r(int n){int r=0,i=32;for(;i--;r=r<<1|n&1,n>>=1);return r;}
```

---

**Updated version** (with changes suggeted by *Allbeert*, *es1024*, and *Dennis*):

```
r(n){int r,i=32;for(;i--;r=r*2|n&1,n>>=1);return r;}
```

Note: Since the second version omits setting `r=0`, the code is assuming that an `int` is 32 bits. If this assumption is false, the function will most likely produce an incorrect result, depending on the initial state of `r` on entry to the function.

---

**Final version** (with further changes suggested by *Dennis* and *Alchymist*):

```
r(n,r,i){for(;32-i++;r=r*2|n&1,n>>=1);return r;}
```

Note: This puts the declaration of the work variables `r` and `i` into the parameter list. Parameters are as follows: `n` is the number to be bit-reversed. `r` and `i` are work variables that must be passed as 0.

Comment: You could remove the `int` function type, and also change `return r` to something like `i=r` since most C compilers tend to leave the last operation's result in the return register. It worked on gcc and cl for me.

Comment: @Allbeert — Ha! Cool. Well, that fails on my compiler (Clang) but I'll definitely take out the `int` function type, since that's still well-defined in C.

Comment: You could shave off another 4 bytes by using `r(n){...}` instead of `r(int n){...}`

Comment: @es1024 — Ah yes! Thank you; will update.

Comment: you can in fact completely drop all type specifiers.

Comment: @FUZxxl you can't drop the `int` in `int r=0,i=32;` unless you move them out of the function body.

Comment: @es1024 Right. But moving them outside will work fine, too.

Comment: Also, substitude `n/=2` for `n>>=1` for one byte and maybe `n*2` for `n<<1` if the precedence works out.

Comment: @FUZxxl — Nope, that only works for unsigned integers. Gotta use `>>` and `<<` for this, unfortunately.

Comment: @Todd huch? That should work just fine.

Comment: For signed integers, `<<1` is defined as `*2` by the C standard, so it has to work. @FUZxxl: `>>` is implementation-defined behavior. The answer works if it performs a *logical* shift, while `/=` would be equivalent to an *arithmetic* shift.

Comment: `r(n,s,i){for(i=32;i--;s=s*2|n&1,n>>=1);return s;}` is a little shorter. Technically, omitting `s=0` is undefined behavior (because of signed integer overflow), but since it's code golf...

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you. Brain fart on my part. Of course `*2` works just as well as `<<1`. Silly me, I wasn't thinking beyond the right shift.

Comment: @Dennis It doesn't look like the answer depends on signed vs. unsigned shift behavior. The answer right-shifts n 32 times and never evaluates any of the sign-bits shifted through.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Shouldn't comment when I'm tired... Arithmetic shift and division are not equivalent; the latter rounds towards zero, while the first rounds towards negative infinity. `-1 >> 1` is `-1` for AS and `2**31 - 1` for LS, while `-1 / 2` is `0`.

Comment: @Todd: Any reason you didn't define `r` and `i` as arguments? Would save three more bytes...

Comment: @Dennis Actually, right shifting negative values is implementation defined in C and -1 >> 1 may very well yield 0, for instance on a sign-and-magnitude architecture.

Comment: @FUZxxl — Good point about the sign of the result of `>>` being implementation-defined. Fortunately, in this case, it's only ever looking at the LSB after a right shift, so whatever goes into the MSB is ignored. :)

Comment: @Dennis — I always thought of that as sort of cheating, since it puts an ugly burden on the caller. But in looking at the rules, it doesn't seem to be disallowed. Also, in this particular case, it allows me to ensure that `r` is initialized to zero. So... thanks, I added that change and now it's down to 49 bytes. :)

Comment: Just call it as `r(n)`. Technically undefined behavior, but should work just fine.

Comment: @Dennis — LOL, that's awesome...hahaha :)

Comment: If we allow passing in 0 initialised values then you can replace i=32;i--; with ;32-i++;

Comment: @Alchymist — Mind blown. Suggestion applied! — thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### x86 assemply, 10 Bytes

```
   f9                      stc    
   d1 d8            1:     rcr    %eax
   74 05                   je     2f
   d1 d2                   rcl    %edx
   f8                      clc    
   eb f7                   jmp    1b
                    2:
```

This assume input in eax, output in edx. (Also, on output eax is zero and CF and ZF are set, if anyone cares).

Instead of a counter, an additional 1 is pushed in in the beginning as end-of data marker

Comment: This has actually the same size as my solution, which is three bytes larger. If you add the `ret` instruction to return from the function and implement cdecl (i.e. change `rcr %eax` to `rcr 4(%esp)` and `rcl %edx` to `rcl %eax`), you end up with one extra byte for the `ret` and another two bytes for the memory reference. Still, a nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

### Julia 0.2, 33 bytes

```
f(n)=parseint(reverse(bits(n)),2)
```

Does what it looks like.

`bits` gives you the bit representation (respecting two's complement). `parseint` doesn't care about two's complement, but returns a 32 bit integer, so the two's complement is simply handled by overflow.

According to the changelogs, overflow detection was added to `parseint` in Julia 0.3, so this might not work any more.

Comment: This is production code, not golfed code! xD I guess Julia's just great.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (E6) 37 <s>39 40 50</s>

Function, number input and returning reversed number. <s>Most basic algorithm, probably can be golfed more with some smart trick.</s>

**Edit** Recursion instead of loop

**Edit 2** Following @bebe suggestion `k*2` instead of `k<<1`

**Edit 3** Something I had missed at all: it's a full 32 bit loop, no need to initialize k. Thanks @FUZxxl

```
R=(v,b=32,k)=>b?R(v>>1,b-1,k*2|v&1):k
```

*It was*

```
R=v=>{for(k=b=0;b++<32;)k+=k+(v&1),v>>=1;return k}
```

**Test** In FireFox console, test using numbers in OP and some more random 16 and 32 bit numbers

```
Bin=x=>('0'.repeat(32)+(x<0?-x-1:x).toString(2)).slice(-32).replace(/./g,d=>x>0?d:1-d),
Dec=x=>(' '.repeat(11)+x).slice(-11),
R16=_=>Math.random()*65536|0,  
R32=_=>(Math.random()*65536<<16)|R16(),  
[-90,486,-984802906,R16(),R16(),R16(),R32(),R32(),R32(),R32()]
 .forEach(n=> console.log(Dec(n)+' '+Bin(n)+' '+Dec(R(n))+' '+Bin(R(n))))
```

**Example of test output**

```
        -90 11111111111111111111111110100110  1711276031 01100101111111111111111111111111
        486 00000000000000000000000111100110  1736441856 01100111100000000000000000000000
 -984802906 11000101010011010001100110100110  1704506019 01100101100110001011001010100011
      45877 00000000000000001011001100110101 -1395851264 10101100110011010000000000000000
      39710 00000000000000001001101100011110  2027487232 01111000110110010000000000000000
      56875 00000000000000001101111000101011  -730136576 11010100011110110000000000000000
-1617287331 10011111100110100010011101011101 -1159439879 10111010111001000101100111111001
-1046352169 11000001101000011110111011010111  -344488573 11101011011101111000010110000011
 1405005770 01010011101111101010111111001010  1408597450 01010011111101010111110111001010
  -35860252 11111101110111001101000011100100   655047615 00100111000010110011101110111111
```

Comment: `b=k=0,R=v=>b++<32?R(v>>1,k+=k+(v&1)):k` for single use
and `R=(v,b=0,k=0)=>b<32?R(v>>1,b+1,k+k+(v&1)):k` is reusable

Comment: @bebe :( I was revising my answer using recursion and lost all to read your comment...

Comment: you're at 38 bytes if `k<<1` becomes `k*2` and `v>>1` becomes `v/2`. it worked for 486. i dont know about other test cases

Comment: @bebe v/2 will not work for negative numbers. 486/512 == 0.9... and 486>>9 == 0, trunc it's the same. But -90/128 == -0.7... and -90>>7 ==-1

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 50

```pyth
print int("{:032b}".format(input()%2**32)[::-1],2)
```

Broadly the same as my Pyth solution. Take the input mod 2**32, convert to 32-bit padded binary, reverse, convert binary sting back to decimal and print.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
li4H#+2bW%32<2b
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

"Free game" joker used: The output will always be an *unsigned* integer.

#### Test cases

```
$ cjam reverse32.cjam <<< 486; echo
1736441856
$ cjam reverse32.cjam <<< -984802906; echo
1704506019
```

#### How it works

```
li   " Read from STDIN and cast to integer. ";
4H#+ " Add 4 ** 17 to avoid special cases. ";
2b   " Convert into array of digits in base 2. ";
W%   " Reverse the order. ";
32<  " Discard the 33th and all following digits. ";
2b   " Convert the array of digits into an integer. ";
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 10 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
2⊥⌽⎕⊤⍨32/2
```

`2⊥` from-base-2 of

`⌽` the reversed

`⎕` numeric input

`⊤⍨` in the number system consisting of

`32/2` 32 bits

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2206%u2190486%20%u22C4%202%u22A5%u233D%u2206%u22A4%u236832/2%20%u22C4%20%u2206%u2190-984802906%20%u22C4%202%u22A5%u233D%u2206%u22A4%u236832/2&run)

Answer (score 3):

## J (<s>17</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes)

```
_32#.@|.@{.#:
```

Here is an explicit definition to explain what it does:

```
3 : '#. |. _32 {. #: y'
```

1. `#: y` represents `y` as a base 2 number using as many places as necessary.
2. `x {. y` takes `|x` (magnitude of `x`) items from `y`, from the front if `x` is positive, from the back if `x` is negative. If we take more items than present, the result is padded with zeroes. `_32 {. #: y` effectively pads `#: y` to 32 bits.
3. `|. y` flips `y`, i.  reverses the order of items in `y`.
4. `#. y`  interprets  `y` as a base-2 number.

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 89

```
def r(n):
 if n<0:n=~n^0xFFFFFFFF
 print int(['','-'][n%2]+'{:032b}'.format(n)[::-1],2)
```

Python represents negative binary numbers as simply `-0b{positive_number}`. So to deal with this, complement negative numbers and then XOR with all 1's.

After that, create the string representation of the integer based on the format `{:032b}` which provides the 32bit representation of the number. Finally, reverse the string and turn it back into an integer.

**EDIT**

Thanks to [@Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) for pointing out a two's complement issue. If `n` ends in a 1 then by two's complement the reversed version would be negative.

Luckily, as explained above, Python likes negative binary numbers in a pretty simple way. Also luckily, Python's `int` function [allows optional sign characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) in its first argument.

So now, add a minus sign if `n` is odd to satisfy two's complement.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks. I missed that possibility at first. The new code handles two's complement better.

Comment: You can golf that a bit more: `['','-'][n%2]` is `'-'*(n%2)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Java function, 64 chars.

```
 int r(int n){int r=0,i=32;for(;i-->0;n>>=1)r=r<<1|n&1;return r;}
```

Should also work in C.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>33</strike> <strike>32</strike> 22

```
v_%"%032db0"vsc%Q^2 32
```

Explanation:

```
                 Q             Evaluated input.
                %Q^2 32        Q mod 2^32. Same 32 bit binary representation as Q.
             vsc%Q^2 32        Convert to binary string, then that to decimal int.
   %"%032db0"vsc%Q^2 32        Pad above number to 32 bits, and append b0.
  _%"%032db0"vsc%Q^2 32        Reverse it.
 v_%"%032db0"vsc%Q^2 32        Eval and print. Due to leading "0b", eval as binary.
```

Golfs:

33 -> 32: Moved add to before reversing to save an end-quote.

32 -> 22: Used Q mod 2^32 instead of complicated machinery. Combined both strings into one.

Test cases:

```
$ cat rev_bits 
v_%"%032db0"vsc%Q^2 32

$ ./pyth.py rev_bits <<< -984802906
1704506019

$ ./pyth.py rev_bits <<< 486
1736441856

$ ./pyth.py rev_bits <<< 0
0
```

Comment: Does it work with result as a big 32 numbers having leftmost bit at 1? In this case it should output a negative integer.

Comment: @edc65 I'm outputting a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

## GNU dc, 27 bytes

```
0?[2~rssr2*+dlsz34>m]dsmx+p
```

#### Output:

```
$ dc revbits.dc <<< 15
4026531840
$ dc revbits.dc <<< 255
4278190080
$ dc revbits.dc <<< 65535
4294901760
$ dc revbits.dc <<< 4294901760
65535
$ dc revbits.dc <<< 4278190080
255
$ dc revbits.dc <<< 4026531840
15
$
```

---

## Bash+coreutils, 45 bytes

```
n=`dc -e2do32^n$1p`
dc -e2i`rev<<<${n: -32}`p
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./revbits.sh 15
4026531840
$ ./revbits.sh 255
4278190080
$ ./revbits.sh 65535
4294901760
$ ./revbits.sh 4294901760
65535
$ ./revbits.sh 4278190080
255
$ ./revbits.sh 4026531840
15
$
```

---

## C function, 89 bytes

Same idea as https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36289/11259 - using the [Stanford bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel).  Not going to win the golfing, but interesting nonetheless:

```
// 89 byte function:
i;r(v){for(i=1;i<32;i*=2)v=v>>i&(1L<<32)/((1<<i)+1)|(v&(1L<<32)/((1<<i)+1))<<i;return v;}

// Test program:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("r(0x0000000f) = 0x%08x\n", r(0x0000000f));
    printf("r(0x000000ff) = 0x%08x\n", r(0x000000ff));
    printf("r(0x0000ffff) = 0x%08x\n", r(0x0000ffff));
    printf("r(0xffffffff) = 0x%08x\n", r(0xffffffff));
    printf("r(0x0f0f0f0f) = 0x%08x\n", r(0x0f0f0f0f));
    printf("r(0xf0f0f0f0) = 0x%08x\n", r(0xf0f0f0f0));
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./revbits 
r(0x0000000f) = 0xf0000000
r(0x000000ff) = 0xff000000
r(0x0000ffff) = 0xffff0000
r(0xffffffff) = 0xffffffff
r(0x0f0f0f0f) = 0xf0f0f0f0
r(0xf0f0f0f0) = 0x0f0f0f0f
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 46 Bytes

[Online Versions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/889f775cac73041fdfb5967887e45659f3b384c7)

```
for(;$i<32;)$t.=$argn>>$i++&1;echo bindec($t);
```

or

```php
<?=bindec(strrev(sprintf("%064b",$argn<<32)));
```

Comment: The `substr` is unnecessary (-12 bytes). You should mention how to run them.

Comment: @Titus have you tried the testcase `-984802906` ?

Comment: Your second version can be improved to match the first: `<?=bindec(strrev(sprintf("%064b",$argn<<32)));`

Comment: @Christoph very nice improvement Thank You

Answer (score 1):

## C# <s>81</s> 74

```
int R(int V){int l,r=l=0,i=1;for(;i>0;i*=2)r|=i*(1&V>>(31-l++));return r;}
```

Bit operations which most likely can be done shorter in all programming languages.

Basically, loop through all powers of 2 up to integer maximum+1(Which turns into a power of two) and since (2,147,483,647+1)=0 I can loop to 0. Bit shift Left to right to move the bit into the first position. Last bit at place 32 goes 31 steps to the right, second last goes 30 etc. So by using AND operator with 1 i will know if it is 1 or 0. If it is 1 I will add the current i value to the result and return it.

```
int R(int V)
{
    int l,r=l=0,i=1;
    for(;i>0;i*=2)
        r|=i*(1&(V>>(31-l++)));
    return r;
 }
```

Comment: Small things, but you can initialize `i` when you declare it, and save a byte by removing `i++` from the for loop, and instead of comparing the result of `1&...` with 0 you can remove the if statement altogether and multiply `i` by the result giving `r|=i*(1&(V>>(31-l++)));` inside the loop

Comment: Clever! I had a feeling I was missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## JS 115

Well that doesn't look good at all :D

```
n=+prompt();alert(eval('0b'+(Array(33).join(0)+(n<0?n>>>0:n).toString(2)).slice(-32).split('').reverse().join('')))
```

@Florian F's method in JS is 53 bytes long:

```
for(n=+prompt(r=0),i=32;i--;n>>=1)r=r<<1|n&1;alert(r)
```

Comment: The `it may be a function` rule means you don't need the alert or prompt

Answer (score 1):

### C# 142

```
using System;using System.Linq;int f(int n){return Convert.ToInt32(new string(Convert.ToString(n,2).PadLeft(32,'0').Reverse().ToArray()),2);}
```

Expanded

```
int f(int n)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(
        new string(
            Convert.ToString(n, 2)
            .PadLeft(32, '0')
            .Reverse()
            .ToArray()), 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 37

Similar to @isaacg's solution.

```py
f=lambda n:int(bin(n%2**32)[:1:-1],2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 160

This isn't the shortest one, however it uses only 24 operations.
Taken from Hacker's Delight book.

Golfed:

```
typedef unsigned U;U R(U&x){U a=-1u/3,b=-1u/5,c=-1u/17,d=65280;x=(x&a)*2|(x/2)&a;x=(x&b)*4|(x/4)&b;x=(x&c)<<4|(x>>4)&c;x=(x<<24)|((x&d)<<8)|((x>>8)&d)|(x>>24);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
unsigned R(unsigned x) {
    x = (x & 0x55555555) <<  1 | (x >>  1) & 0x55555555; 
    x = (x & 0x33333333) <<  2 | (x >>  2) & 0x33333333; 
    x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) <<  4 | (x >>  4) & 0x0F0F0F0F; 
    x = (x << 24) | ((x & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((x >> 8) & 0xFF00) | (x >> 24); 
    return x; 
}
```

Comment: This is a code golf question. Please try to reduce the number of characters in your solution, not the number of operations.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 145  - no bitwise operations

Bit-twiddling strikes me as the antithesis of Haskell, so I've avoided any use of bitwise operators.  The resulting program is certainly not the shortest contestant, but I thought the use of math instead of bit-twiddling was interesting at least.

```
import Data.Tuple
import Data.List
f m=foldl1((+).(*2))$take 32$(unfoldr(\n->if n==0 then Nothing else Just$swap$divMod n 2)$mod m$2^32)++[0,0..]
```

#### Explanation

```
f m=foldl1((+).(*2))$take 32$(unfoldr(\n->if n==0 then Nothing else Just$swap$divMod n 2)$mod m$2^32)++[0,0..]
    |------5-------|---4----|--------------------------2---------------------------------|----1-----|---3----|
```

1. uses modulo to bring the result into 32-bit range
2. constructs a list of `0`s and `1`s, least significant bit first by repeatedly dividing by 2 and taking the remainder
3. concatenates an infinite list of `0`s to the end of this list
4. grabs the first 32 elements of the list (These last two were needed to ensure the list is actually 32 bits long.)
5. converts a list of `0` and `1` into an integer assuming the *most* significant bit is first (repeated double and add).

I'm not quite sure what constitutes "the standard library" in Haskell so I assumed Data.Tuple and Data.List were OK (they are pretty standard).

Also, the output is an *unsigned* 32-bit integer since changing that would cost me bytes: I'm arguing this under "omissions are free game".

Comment: Standard library: what ships with the language. This includes system headers for C, the 4000+ classes and methods in Java's (most are irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>46</s> 41 bytes

[try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9ddf7272f067307ec3303d5c7d6378265a5c311)

```php
while($i<32)$r=$r*2|$argn>>$i++&1;echo$r;
```

bitwise ... more or less. Run as pipe with `php -nR '<code>'`.

**PHP, 46 bytes**

```php
while($i<32)$r|=($argn>>$i&1)<<31-$i++;echo$r;
```

a pure bitwise solution; run as pipe with `-nR`.

**PHP, <s>47</s> 59 bytes**

```php
<?=bindec(str_pad(strrev(substr(decbin($argn),-32)),32,0));
```

another built-in approach; save to file and run as pipe with `-F`.

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb machine code, 10 bytes

```
00000000: 01 20 49 08 40 41 fc d3 70 47            . I.@A..pG
```

As per request, this does not use the `rbit` instruction.

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .globl rbit
    .thumb_func
    // input: r1
    // output: r0
rbit:
    // sentinel bit
    movs    r0, #1
.Lloop:
    // shift the lowest bit into the carry flag
    lsrs    r1, #1
    // shift in with adc, put highest bit in carry flag
    adcs    r0, r0
    // when the carry is set we flipped all 32 bits
    bcc     .Lloop
    // return
    bx      lr
```

---

## ARM Thumb machine code (with builtins), 6 bytes

```
00000000: 90 fa a0 f0 70 47                   ....pG
```

This is literally the `rbit` instruction that was explicitly disallowed but I am providing for reference

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .globl rbit_cheater
    .thumb_func
    // input: r0
    // output: r0
rbit_cheater:
    // Trivialize the challenge.
    rbit   r0, r0
    // Return
    bx     lr
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - 60

```
$_=unpack"N",pack"B*",scalar reverse unpack"B32",pack"N",$_
```

+1 for the p flag (let me know if I'm counting this wrong).

Run with:

```
echo 486 | perl -pe'$_=unpack"N",pack"B32",scalar reverse unpack"B32",pack"N",$_'
```

Answer (score 0):

### C++ 69

```
int r(int n){int e=0,i=0;for(;i<32;i++)e|=((n>>i)&1)<<31-i;return e;}
```

Comment: @bebe what are these `e;i;`? Declarations without type are not a valid C++. For variables it's not even valid C.

Comment: @Ruslan i didn't recognize '++' in the title, sorry. (i wouldn't agree with your second statement)

Comment: `int r(int n){int e=0,i=0;for(;i<32;)e=e*2|1&n>>i++;return e;}` 61 bytes :)

Answer (score 0):

### R, 45

```
f=function(x)packBits(intToBits(x)[32:1],"i")
```

Examples:

```
f(486)
# [1] 1736441856
f(-984802906)
# [1] 1704506019
```

Always just shy of the Python answers. That damn function keyword.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <del>43</del> 41 bytes

`def r(n)(0..31).inject(0){|a,b|a*2+n[b]}end`

In Ruby, using the bracket index notation (foo[i]) returns the bit at the nth place.

#### --Edit--

Refactoring the `inject` functionality shaves a couple bytes

`def r(n)z=0;32.times{|i|z=z*2+n[i]};z;end`

Answer (score 0):

## Perl5: 46

```perl
sub r{for(0..31){$a=$a*2|$_[0]&1;$_[0]>>=1}$a}
```

Nothing fancy. It shifts output left, copy lsb before shifting source right.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, <s>202</s> <s>156</s> 142

```
#(read-string (let [s (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~2r" %)](apply str (reverse (apply str (concat (repeat (- 32 (count s)) "0") s "r2"))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl (37+1)

basically a port of the C solution by Todd Lehman

`perl -E '$t=<>;map$r=2*$r|1&$t>>$_,0..31;say$r'`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

```
(n,m=32)=>(--m&&f(n,m)*2)|n>>m&1
```

Wrote this while trying to solve [Bit-Reversal Permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83373/bit-reversal-permutations) - it didn't help there, but it works fine here!

Answer (score 0):

## PASM (P8X32A assembly language), 4 bytes, 1 instruction

```
REV $1ef, #0
```

#### Assembles to:

```
00 DE FF 3C
```

#### Explanation:

Reverses the low 32-0 bits (e.g. all of them) in place in location 0x1ef.

Quite why this instruction exists is a mystery to me.  Probably to make life extremely awkward for emulator authors. :)

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>40</s> 38 bytes

using a recursive function and multiplication by 1u to cast from int to unsigned

```c
R(I){return I?I<<31|R(I*1u/2)*1u/2:0;}
```

edit:
replaced right shift with division by 2

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2H3P0jDU7O6KLWktChPwdPe08bG2LAGKKZlWKpvpAkmrQysa/9n5pUo5CZm5mloclVzcRYUAflpGkqqKTF5SjoKQRqGmprWWIRNLMywS@haWphYGBhZGkDkofYbWHPV/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
b32jð0:RC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ydgo6/AGA6sg5///DY2MTQA)

Uses unsigned integers.

```
b   convert input to binary
32j pad to length 32
ð0: replace spaces by zeroes
R   reverse
C   convert to decimal
```

I don't know if that counts as "omissions", but if input and output are allowed in binary, then the one-byter `R` will do the work.

Comment: First of all, OP explicitly stated that I/O must be in decimal, and even if this wasn't the case `R` still breaks the rule that built-ins aren't allowed.

Comment: Ok, then the single "R" isn't allowed, but the 9-byte answer is.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```
[ 32 <bits> reverse bits>number ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoZeUWVKsUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiUJxaWJqal5xarGDNVa1gYmGmoGtpYWJhYGRpYKZQ@z9awdhIwQaky06hKLUstag4VQHMyyvNTUotUoj9n5tYoKD3HwA)

### Explanation:

- `32 <bits>` represent an integer as a virtual sequence of 32 bits (booleans)
- `reverse` reverse the sequence
- `bits>number` convert a sequence of booleans to an integer