# What is the reverse (binary) bit number?

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion, binary

So you are given a **POSITIVE** base 10 (decimal) number. Your job is to reverse the binary digits and return that base 10 number.

#### Examples:

```
1 => 1 (1 => 1)
2 => 1 (10 => 01)
3 => 3 (11 => 11)
4 => 1 (100 => 001)
5 => 5 (101 => 101)
6 => 3 (110 => 011)
7 => 7 (111 => 111)
8 => 1 (1000 => 0001)
9 => 9 (1001 => 1001)
10 => 5 (1010 => 0101)
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the solution that uses the least bytes wins.

This is [A030101](http://oeis.org/A030101) in the OEIS.

Comment: Does "reverse the bits" mean reverse its binary digits? Sometimes it can also mean [invert every bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT).

Comment: Yes. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83373/14215) and [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36213/14215) are veeeeery similar.

Comment: [OEIS A030101](http://oeis.org/A030101).

Comment: "base 10" Any particular reason why?

Comment: Thought I found a really weird property, but 9 broke it. For all examples other than nine, if you reverse the binary number and multiply ones by their index and sum... Then you take that sum and get the "ath prime", it works for all of the numbers that result in primes.

Answer (score 22):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```py
lambda n:int(bin(n)[:1:-1],2)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#K1KwVYj5n5OYm5SSqJBnlZlXopGUmaeRpxltZWilaxirY6T5v6AIJFykYWiiqfkfAA)

This is an anonymous, unnamed function which returns the result.

---

First, `bin(n)` converts the argument to a binary string. We would ordinarily reverse this with the slice notation `[::-1]`. This reads the string with a step of **-1**, i.e. backwards. However, binary strings in Python are prefixed with an `0b`, and therefore we give the slicing's second argument as **1**, telling Python to read backwards terminating at index **1**, thus not reading indexes **1** and **0**.

Now that we have the backwards binary string, we pass it to `int(...)` with the second argument as **2**. This reads the string as a base 2 integer, which is then implicity returned by the lambda expression.

Comment: Beat you by 9 seconds.

Comment: @mbomb007 I beat you a few seconds too I guess, but I made a small mistake so I deleted mine xP

Comment: @mbomb007 http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10812/14215

Comment: Oh, haven't seen that. That's a recent meta post. I disagree with it, though.

Comment: @mbomb007 so my answer is invalid because you clicked the post button 9 seconds before hand? Just because we reach the same golf at the same time doesn't mean we have to delete any answers. If anything, blame the 0-effort question.

Comment: Not invalid, but definitely pointless. If I had been slower, I'd simply delete mine and post a comment on the faster one that I came up with it too.

Comment: Slower or not, it's leading in the vote count.

Comment: Probably because the sour grapes are amusing. At least for me.

Comment: @steenbergh Who cares? Same code, same score.

Answer (score 17):

## Python, 29 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(bin(n)[:1:-1],2)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBnlZlXopGUmaeRpxltZWilaxirY6T5v6AIKKyQpmFooPkfAA)

Comment: This is what I would have done. ;)

Answer (score 13):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld*

```
f=(n,q)=>n?f(n>>1,q*2|n%2):q
```

This basically calculates the reverse one bit at a time: We start with **q = 0**; while **n** is positive, we multiply **q** by 2, sever the last bit off of **n** with `n>>1`, and add it to **q** with `|n%2`. When **n** reaches 0, the number has been successfully reversed, and we return **q**.

Thanks to JS's long built-in names, solving this challenge the easy way takes 44 bytes:

```
n=>+[...n.toString(2),'0b'].reverse().join``
```

Using recursion and a string, you can get a 32 byte solution that does the same thing:

```
f=(n,q='0b')=>n?f(n>>1,q+n%2):+q
```

Comment: `f=(n,q)=>n?f(n>>1,q*2|n%2):q` almost works. But sadly not for `n=0`.

Comment: @Arnauld OP has not yet replied as to whether the input will always be positive, but if so, then 0 doesn't have to be handled.

Comment: This is a late follow-up, but the input is now known to be always positive.

Answer (score 10):

## Java 8, <s>53</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

- *-4 bytes thanks to Titus*
- *-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

This is a lambda expression which has the same principle as [ETH's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105633/60919) (although recursion would have been too verbose in Java, so we loop instead):

```Java
x->{int t=0;for(;x>0;x/=2)t+=t+x%2;return t;}
```

[**Try it online!**](https://repl.it/FAsU/9)

This can be assigned with `IntFunction<Integer> f = ...`, and then called with `f.apply(num)`. Expanded, ungolfed and commented, it looks like this:

```Java
x -> { 
    int t = 0;           // Initialize result holder   
    while (x > 0) {      // While there are bits left in input:
        t <<= 1;         //   Add a 0 bit at the end of result
        t += x%2;        //   Set it to the last bit of x
        x >>= 1;         //   Hack off the last bit of x
    }              
    return t;            // Return the final result
};
```

Comment: Save 3 bytes with `t*2` instead of `(t<<1)`, one more with moving that calculation from loop head to loop body. Can You use `x` instead of `x>0` for the condition?

Comment: @Titus not without an explicit cast to a boolean, but thanks for the other tips! Also just realised that `x>>=1` can be replaced with `x/=2` as it will automatically be integer division.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU49a8MwEN3zK45AwUZE@YAuVeSx0CFTxjaD6sjmXEUS0ik4BP92R0oz3L0Hd@9jUFe1cl7b4fw3t0bFCAeFFu4LAJ9@DbYQSVGGq8MzXPKtOlJA23@fQIU@1uUTYMg@PBEa3iXbEjrLvyx9vvg@c93r0EAHEuZx1dzREpDciM6FSozNRoxruauJSWLj204ETSlYIDHNxV48Q56rCIoY5VYA7uX2PQNjrx4Ax1skfeEuEfe5JxlbIVt@/NCSdVx5b24V1vW/4bQoM80P) (Changed `t=t*2+` to `t+=t+`.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen nice one!

Answer (score 9):

## J, 6 bytes

```
|.&.#:
```

`|.` reverse

`&.` under

`#:` base 2

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
BUḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@8U@nBHy////w0NAA)

```
B   # convert to binary
 U  # reverse
  Ḅ # convert to decimal
```

Comment: That's pretty short, BUB

Comment: Hmm... Is that really 3 *bytes*?

Comment: @aioobe Yep. Jelly uses it's own [code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) where each of these characters is 1 byte.

Comment: Cool, thanks! <pad>

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
#~IntegerReverse~2&
```

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

-1 byte thanks to gurka and -1 byte thanks to anatolyg:

```c
r;f(n){for(r=n&1;n/=2;r+=r+n%2);return r;}
```

Previous 44 bytes solution:

```c
r;f(n){r=n&1;while(n/=2)r=2*r+n%2;return r;}
```

Previous 48 bytes solution:

```c
r;f(n){r=0;while(n)r=2*(r+n%2),n/=2;return r/2;}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```c
r;
f(n){
 for(
  r=n&1;
  n/=2;
  r+=r+n%2
 );
 return r;}
}


main() {
#define P(x) printf("%d %d\n",x,f(x))
P(1);
P(2);
P(3);
P(4);
P(5);
P(6);
P(7);
P(8);
P(9);
P(10);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `r` already initialized to zero here `r;f(n){r=0;`, e.g. the `r=0;` is unnecessary? Also minor typo: "Previous **48** bytes solution"

Comment: @gurka The function should be reusable.

Comment: I think that `for` loops are always at least as short as `while` loops, and often shorter.

Comment: @anatolyg something like: `r;f(n){for(r=n&1;n/=2;r=2*r+n%2);return r;}`? 1 byte shorter, but I'm unsure if it's valid C (C99).

Comment: Yes; also, turn `=` into `+=` to make it shorter and more obfuscated

Answer (score 7):

## Labyrinth, 23 bytes

```
?_";:_2
  :   %
 @/2_"!
```

Well, this is awkward... this returns the reverse BINARY number...
Thanks @Martin Ender for pointing out both my bug and my ID 10T error.
So this doesn't work, I'll have to find another solution.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and nice first post! Just completing a challenge in a language like Labyrinth can be very difficult. Around here, we usually prefix the first line of an answer with one or two hashes, to make it show as a header: `# Labyrinth, 89 bytes`

Comment: Did you accidentally omit a leading space from the second row? As it stands, the program would just bounce back and forth on the first line because the `_` are on the junctions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just noticed that this isn't valid regardless, because the challenge asks for the base-10 representation of the reversed number, not its binary representation.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
->n{("%b"%n).reverse.to_i 2}
```

"%b" % n formats the input n as a binary string, reverse, then convert back to a number

Usage/Test cases:

```
m=->n{("%b"%n).reverse.to_i 2}
m[1] #=> 1
m[2] #=> 1
m[3] #=> 3
m[4] #=> 1
m[5] #=> 5
m[6] #=> 3
m[7] #=> 7
m[8] #=> 1
m[9] #=> 9
m[10] #=> 5
```

Comment: @Titus I think you misunderstand the answer. `2` is the base he is converting to, and `n` is the input. `->args{return value}` is the ruby lambda syntax

Comment: Can you remove the parentheses in `.to_i(2)`?

Comment: @Cyoce sure enough, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
bRC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@58U5Pz/v6EBAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 63 bytes

```java
a->a.valueOf(new StringBuffer(a.toString(a,2)).reverse()+"",2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TY49C8IwFEXn9Fc8OiWoQV2LDm6C4uBYHJ71pQTatOSjKqW/vaZUxPW8e899bbhXuoCiQufgjNpAnzDn0UeojSersCA4YX1/IPQTAhsMP8ZTSRZeIoMhS1g7a77FrtEPqKOMX73VpsxvgLZ0YnKzr0vtRlztUXZYBboobugJc/oQlCLLUfpmBhyXWyGkpY6sIy4WaRpBNjIWl9n17TzVsgletjHtK8OV/PvxtzC9kK9vQohYG5JhHDfrDw)

Thanks to poke for -12 bytes and to Cyoce for -8 bytes!

Comment: Even though REPL submissions are allowed, they still follow the rule that you can't assume input is in predefined variables (like `a` in this context)

Comment: @FlipTack Oops. It was originally a function before I remembered the repl existed

Comment: Well I suppose you can just do `a->` at the start to make it a lambda expression and cut out the `println`. That might make it shorter.

Comment: Also, in the future, use `print` instead of `println` for golfing :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this prints the reverse binary string, rather than evaluating it as a new integer.

Comment: @FlipTack I think it works now. Only gained a byte.

Comment: `Long.toString(a,2)` saves 4 bytes over `Long.toBinaryString(a)`

Comment: `StringBuffer` saves a byte over `StringBuilder`

Comment: @Poke Thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: `a` is of type `Long` so you should be able to use `a.parseLong` and `a.toString`. It will give a warning about using a static method in a non-static way or something but that's fine. Saves 6 bytes.

Comment: `a.valueOf` instead of `a.parseLong` should save a byte

Comment: Could you do `+""` instead of `.toString()`?

Comment: @Cyoce Was about to comment this, but then I saw yours at the bottom. +1 from me, that should definitely be possible for the empty `.toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Shaggy

```
¢ÔÍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9Ciw1MO9/7/b2gAAA)

Comment: Nice, exactly what I had. The `)` could be a space too :-)

Comment: This can now be `¢ÔÍ` or `¤ÔÍ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 19 bytes

```
{:2(.base(2).flip)}
```

Comment: Where is the input?

Comment: This is a function that takes a single parameter `$_`.  It isn't mentioned by name, but the `base` method is called on it.

Comment: @Titus in Perl 6 a Block is a type of Code, which is to say it's a callable object. The above is an expression that you can take and assign to a variable like a function or lambda in another language, or call directly — `{:2(.base(2).flip)}(10)` at the REPL will print 5. So it meets the standard code-golf criteria for a function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)/Unix utilities, <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```bash
dc -e2i`dc -e2o?p|rev`p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SrKCbapSZAKHz7QtqilLLEgr@/zc0@A8A)

Comment: A courageous take on Bash! 

Comment: @juniorRubyist -- Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 36 bytes

```
0!b=b
a!b=div a 2!(b+b+mod a 2)
(!0)
```

Same algorithm (and length!) as ETHproductions’ [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105633/3852) answer.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 33 bytes

```php
<?=bindec(strrev(decbin($argn)));
```

convert to base2, reverse string, convert to decimal. Save to file and run as pipe with `-F`.

**no builtins:**

**iterative, 41 bytes**

```php
for(;$n=&$argn;$n>>=1)$r+=$r+$n%2;echo$r;
```

While input has set bits, pop a bit from input and push it to output. Run as pipe with `-nR`.

**recursive, 52 bytes**

```php
function r($n,$r=0){return$n?r($n>>1,$r*2+$n%2):$r;}
```

Comment: @JörgHülsermann The 44 bytes have `$r+=$r`. But I actually don´t remember why I put that in front.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
BPXB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@8UEOH0/78ZAA)

#### Explanation

```
B     % Input a number implicitly. Convert to binary array
P     % Reverse array
XB    % Convert from binary array to number. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
i_.BQ2
```

[Test suite available here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=i_.BQ2&input=2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
i_.BQ2
    Q     eval(input())
  .B      convert to binary
 _        reverse
i    2    convert from base 2 to base 10
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 40 bytes

```
i=>BigInt(BigInt(i)toString 2 reverse,2)
```

#### Usage:

```
val f:(Int=>Any)=i=>BigInt(BigInt(i)toString 2 reverse,2)
f(10) //returns 5
```

#### Explanation:

```
i =>          // create an anonymous function with a parameter i
  BigInt(       //return a BigInt contructed from
    BigInt(i)     //i converted to a BigInt
    toString 2    //converted to a binary string
    reverse       //revered
    ,           
    2             //interpreted as a binary string
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](http://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/74163)

```apl
2⊥∘⊖2∘⊥⍣¯1
```

[Try it!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u21902%u22A5%u2218%u22962%u2218%u22A5%u2363%AF1&run)

Thanks to @Adám for 2 bytes.

#### How it works:

This is a tacit function. To use it, it has to be assigned a name (like `f←`) and then called over an input; for the test cases: `f 1`, `f 2`, etc.

```apl
2⊥∘⊖2∘⊥⍣¯1  # Main function; tacit.
       ⍣¯1  # invert
    2∘⊥     # convert from base 2 (which is inverted to 'convert to base 2')
  ∘⊖        # flip, then
2⊥          # convert from base 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
#+##&~Fold~Reverse[#~IntegerDigits~2]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 46 bytes

```
{0.parseInt(0.toBinaryString(it).reverse(),2)}
```

Comment: Does this take any input?

Comment: @Titus `it` refers to the argument given to a block IIRC

Comment: I love how this is the same length as my [Java answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105653/60919) - Java and groovy, unite!

Comment: @FlipTack I'm gonna go cry now.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
ri2bW%2b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UaZQUrmqU9P@/GQA)

#### Explanation

```
ri          e# Read integer
  2b        e# Convert to binary array
    W%      e# Reverse array
      2b    e# Convert from binary array to number. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 62 bytes

```
@set/an=%1/2,r=%2+%1%%2
@if %n% gtr 0 %0 %n% %r%*2
@echo %r%
```

Explanation: On the first pass, `%1` contains the input parameter while `%2` is empty. We therefore evaluate `n` as half of `%1` and `r` as `+%1` modulo 2 (the `%` operator has to be doubled to quote it). If `n` is not zero, we then call ourselves tail recursively passing in `n` and an expression that gets evaluated on the next pass effectively doubling `r` each time.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 98 bytes

```
using System.Linq;using b=System.Convert;a=>b.ToInt64(string.Concat(b.ToString(a,2).Reverse()),2);
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 55 bytes

```
sum(2^((length(y<-rev(miscFuncs::bin(scan()))):1)-1)*y)
```

Reads input from stdin and consequently uses the `bin` function from the `miscFuncs` package to convert from decimal to a binary vector.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 19 bytes

No builtin base conversion!

```
$&2%v2/;FL:vK2*;OS#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/19FzUi1zEjf2s3HqszbSMvaP1j5////hgYA)

Pushy has two stacks, and this answer makes use of this extensively.

There are two parts two this program. First, `$&2%v2/;F`, converts the number to its reverse binary representation:

```
            \ Implicit: Input is an integer on main stack.
$      ;    \ While i != 0:
 &2%v       \   Put i % 2 on auxiliary stack
     2/     \   i = i // 2 (integer division)
        F   \ Swap stacks (so result is on main stack)
```

Given the example 10, the stacks would appear as following on each iteration:

```
1: [10]
2: []

1: [5]
2: [0]

1: [2]
2: [0, 1]

1: [1]
2: [0, 1, 0]

1: [0]
2: [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

We can see that after the final iteration, `0, 1, 0, 1` has been created on the second stack - the reverse binary digits of 10, `0b1010`.

The second part of the code, `L:vK2*;OS#`, is taken from my previous answer which converts [binary to decimal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102269/60919). Using the method decsribed and explained in that answer, it converts the binary digits on the stack into a base 10 integer, and prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 22 bytes

```
_2/?+:{!
}    "
++:{%#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P8/3kjfXtuqWpGrVgEIlLi0gRxV5f//DQ0MAA)

#### Explanation

The idea is to disassemble the input bit-by-bit while assembling the output from the other end. Luckily, it's easiest to deconstruct a number from the right, and build one up from the left, so this automatically reverses the bits. We'll generally be keeping what's left of the input on top the main stack, and what we've already computed of the result on top of the auxiliary stack.

```
_2/  When the program starts out, this doesn't really do anything, because it
     just divides an implicit zero by 2.
?+   Read an integer N from STDIN and add it to the implicit zero on top of 
     the stack.

     The main loop starts here:

:    Duplicate what's left of N. This is also used as the conditional to end
     the loop. Once this reaches zero, the IP moves straight ahead, exiting
     the loop. Otherwise, the IP turns south which continues the loop.
#    Push the stack depth, 2.
%    Take N modulo 2, i.e. get its least significant bit.
{    Fetch the intermediate result R from the auxiliary stack.
:+   Double it (shifting its existing bits left by one position).
+    Add the bit we just extracted from N to R.
}    Put R back on the auxiliary stack.
_2/  Divide N by 2, dropping its least significant bit.
?+   We're at EOF, so ? just pushes zero and the + gets rid of that zero.

     Then the main loop starts over.
     When we exit the loop (once N is zero), this bit is run:

{    Retrieve R from the auxiliary stack.
!    Print it.
     The IP hits a dead end and turns around.
{:+? Various shenanigans which simply leave a zero on top of the stack.
/    Terminates the program due to the attempted division by zero.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
bṘB
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQQSIsIiIsImLhuZhCIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Converts to a binary string, reverses it, then puts it back in base 10.

Comment: So then when will you be back?

Comment: Btw the link doesn't have any input in it.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 18 bytes

```
{2/:|X@&|\X:0b\:x}
```

Example:

```
k){2/:|X@&|\X:0b\:x}6
3
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5 (5.12+), 32 bytes

```
say oct reverse sprintf"%bb0",<>
```

(Input on stdin, output on stdout, requires `-E` or `-M5.012` at no cost).

Straightforward but not all that short. Too bad "reverse" and "sprintf" are such weighty keywords.

`oct` is an odd legacy name; `oct "123"` gives the decimal equivalent of octal 123 as you'd expect, but `oct "0x123"` interprets its input as hex and `oct "0b101"` interprets it as binary.

Comment: You can shave a couple of characters off this by including the `0b` in the `sprintf` statement:
`say oct reverse sprintf"%bb0",<>`

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>94</s> 89 bytes

Golfed:

```
int x(int n){return Long.parseLong(new StringBuffer(Long.toString(n,2)).reverse()+"",2)};
```

Ungolfed:

```
int x(int n)
{
    return Integer.parseInt(new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(n, 2)).reverse() + "", 2);
}
```

<sup>5 bytes saved thanks to @corvus_192</sup>

Comment: You can use `Long.parseLong` and `Long.toString` to save a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 167 bytes

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 {
 var bytes= Convert.ToString(i, 2);
 var value= Convert.ToInt32(byteValue.Reverse()); 
 console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

**Explanation:**

Here I will iterate n values and each time iterated integer value is convert to byte value then reverse that byte value and that byte value is converted to integer value.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I don't know much about C# but you most certainly have a good deal of extra whitespace I would recommend removing.  It also is not clear how I/O is dealt with in this submission.  It is standard to either write a function or to use `STDIN` (I think that is `console.Read()` but you would probably know better than I would) and `STDOUT`.   Anyway, welcome to the site if you want more experienced advice in golfing C# I would recommend http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because it doesn't work at all. `.Reverse()` returnes `IEnumerable<char>`. As `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't have an overload for IEnumerable it throws an exception. Also the answer doesn't follow the rules for code golf: 1)As nothing is specified the submission has to be a [full program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) not just a snippet. 2)`using` statements [must be included in the byte count](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/383/should-imports-includes-count-in-golf)

Answer (score 0):

**c/c++ 136 bytes**

```
uint8_t f(uint8_t n){int s=8*sizeof(n)-ceil(log2(n));n=(n&240)>>4|(n&15)<<4;n=(n&204)>>2|(n&51)<<2;n=(n&172)>>1|(n&85)<<1;return(n>>s);}
```

It's not going to win, but I wanted to take a different approach in c/c++
120 bytes in the function

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t f(uint8_t n){
    int s=8*sizeof(n)-ceil(log2(n));
    n=(n&240)>>4|(n&15)<<4;
    n=(n&204)>>2|(n&51)<<2;
    n=(n&172)>>1|(n&85)<<1;
    return (n>>s);
}

int main(){
    printf("%u\n",f(6));
    return 0;
}
```

To elaborate on what I am doing, I used the log function to determine the number of bits utilized by the input.  Than a series of three bit shifts left/right, inside/outside, even/odd which flips the entire integer. Finally a bit shift to shift the number back to the right. Using decimals for bit shifts instead of hex is a pain but it saved a few bytes.

Comment: You do need to include the function declaration, so this is actually [163 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#uint8%5ft%20f%28uint8%5ft%20n%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20int%20s%3D8%2asizeof%28n%29-ceil%28log2%28n%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20n%3D%28n%26240%29%3E%3E4%7C%28n%2615%29%3C%3C4%3B%0A%20%20%20%20n%3D%28n%26204%29%3E%3E2%7C%28n%2651%29%3C%3C2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20n%3D%28n%26172%29%3E%3E1%7C%28n%2685%29%3C%3C1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%28n%3E%3Es%29%3B%0A%7D). Although, if you remove the extraneous whitespace, you could shorten it to 136.

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc1NCoMwEAXgfU4RLA1JqTUGtYI/J@lGYtSAjhKTlfXsNtrZDPM9eCOXJeylPG4a5OhahcvVtnp@DbWnaZmNLafGDv5GGizuqINV96BaLIfGYGDbyWuVh1LpkY5zLygwVkAFUZyROP3Cw2@R8IsSksZeEiJ4UhhlnQEKkSB55lWQ@M1ZXa/FfpytU6OBsg1hP4vx0tHg7j4QPDua@R9X8C/BvEA7On4 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Pari/GP , 28 byte

The value to be "reversed" is expected in variable a; i.e. do `a=37` first.
Then execute the cmd. Because Pari/GP is interpreting you do not need to add an extra `print(b)` because referencing a variable or a result just prints it to the console:

```
  b=a%2;while(a\=2,b+=b+a%2);b
```

Example:

```
  a=37
  b=a%2;while(a\=2,b+=b+a%2);b
  \\ printed result is: 41
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S7Q1MfyfZJuoamRdnpGZk6qRGGNrpJOkbZukDRTTtE76X1CUmVeikaT5HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 41 bytes

```
INPUT N
WHILE N:T=T+T+N MOD 2N=N>>1WEND?T
```

Basically a port of the C/Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>41</s> 29 bytes

```
2 base drop >s rev >n decimal
```

**Usage**

```
ok> 37 2 base drop >s rev >n decimal .
41
```

**Test case**

```
: f 2 base drop >s s:rev >n decimal ; 
( dup . " => " . f . cr ) 1 10 loop

1 => 1
2 => 1
3 => 3
4 => 1
5 => 5
6 => 3
7 => 7
8 => 1
9 => 9
10 => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala 47 bytes

Handles BigInt

```
((i:BigInt)=>BigInt(i.toString(2).reverse,2))([Number to Reverse])
```

if only we could:

```
(i=>BigInt(i.toString(2).reverse,2))([Number to Reverse])
```

or

```
(BigInt(_.toString(2).reverse,2))([Number to Reverse])
```

#### Example (REPL):

```
scala> ((i:Int)=>BigInt(i.toString(2).reverse,2))(100)
res1: scala.math.BigInt = 19
```

#### Example (in Situ):

```
object main extends App {
    val arg = Option(args).getOrElse(Array[String]("100"))
    (BigInt(arg(0)) to BigInt(arg(1))).map((n)=>
    (println(n + "-->" + BigInt(n.toString(2).reverse, 2))))
}
```

run:

```
run 20 30
```

result:

```
[debug] Waiting for thread run-main-23 to terminate.
20-->5
21-->21
22-->13
23-->29
24-->3
25-->19
26-->11
27-->27
28-->7
29-->23
30-->15
[debug]         Thread run-main-23 exited.
```

Answer (score 0):

## C 41 bytes

```
g(i,r){for(r=0;r+=r+i%2,i/=2;);return r;}
```

Input in "i" output the result

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1BCoMwEEbhfU8RhMAMGWl0O81NuilBw79oWgazEs8edf0@eHksOfdeCGK8rz8jS1EtJAvws@CZZmW1ZWtWnenRvx9U4h11c9Db4/J4TZOGAHZ/u8pKQyHfJHLy7V0HcRB3LyKzHo9@Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 52 bytes

```
(parse-integer(reverse(format()"~b"(read))):radix 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlXAqQSi4pTdYHM1PTUIo2i1LJUIF8jLb8oN7FEQ1OpLkkJKJiYoqmpaVWUmJJZoWCk@V/zv6EBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 32 bytes

```
f(n)=parseint(reverse(bin(n)),2)
```

gives a warning but still runs

Comment: Is this a full program or a function, because it looks like a snippet? If this is a snippet, you can change it so that it conforms with our rules.

Comment: if you run this exact code on the interpreter it returns the value. If it must return using the return keyword, I will add that in. other than that, and input, this is a full program. just substitute n for any number (input was not specified in the rules, unless thats a default requirement)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
ḋ↔ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aFtu/qOmxqJD2/4/3NH9qG0KkPz//78hlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJZehAQA)

## Explanation

Here's an explanation, even if there's not much to it:

```
     -- implicit input N    | 10
  ḋ  -- convert to base2    | [1,0,1,0]
 ↔   -- reverse             | [0,1,0,1]
ḋ    -- convert from base2  | 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 44 bytes

```js
f=i=>(a=0,(x=i=>i?(a=a*2+i%2,x(i>>1)):a)(i))

for(i=1;i<10;i++){console.log(i,f(i))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 14 bytes

```
D,f,@,BBBR2@Bb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQcfJySnIyMEp6f///4YGAA)

### How it works

```
D,f,@,   - Create a monadic function named f. Example argument: [10]
      BB - Convert to binary;     STACK = ['1010']
      BR - Reverse the top value; STACK = ['0101']
      2  - Push 2;                STACK = ['0101' 2]
      @  - Reverse the stack;     STACK = [2 '0101']
      Bb - Convert from base;     STACK = [5]
         - Implicit return
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 6 bytes

```
2Bi2iB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9/IKdMo0@k/kAEA)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 46 bytes

```
say x2d(b2x(reverse(trunc(x2b(d2x(arg(1)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 49 bytes

A function literal based off my [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105653/60919):

```go
func(x int)(t int){for;x>0;x/=2{t+=t+x%2};return}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc5NCoMwFATgdXKKR0BIjK0/S9N4hh6gG1EjUnyRECEgOXuq3qCrmc18zGzT1g/ffp5g7Reky7pZ54GZ1TNa5snsOPAAC3rB/R2HsU6FrlKh1M3hpfYyZE1UbvK7w5jyktJrdXtcwEGJgVbD39K5sw6w1TUoQHhpqKurSXmZ5Hz4fLvTMZxlIzw6yMYPsgKwAMNRCKAkEhrTDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃrḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4M3IlRTElQjglODImZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMCZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
ḃrḂ  # Implicit input
ḃ    # To binary
 r   # Reverse
  Ḃ  # From binary
     # Implicit output
```